# Fields keep disappearing in R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

This is the story. I had a bunch of problems with R.java and i'm finally solving them.
R.Java didn't regenerate until i created a new project and copied the old codes in the new one and finally R.java wanted to regenerate and keep in my project when i clean it.

The thing is, when i try to create a field *(i.e :source, activity_main, etc.)*, save all files and build, the error keeps showing and the field line eclipse created for me is gone.

Here's the code :

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Lexiconda");
    setContentView(com.indestructibles.reproductormp3.R.id.activity_main);

    initialize(0);
}





  private void createMenu(Menu menu){
    }
    MenuItem miStop = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Stop");{
        miStop.setIcon(com.indestructibles.reproductormp3.R.id.btnStop);
    }
    MenuItem miSource = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "Source");{
        miSource.setIcon(com.indestructibles.reproductormp3.R.id.source);
    }
```

Any help. please?. I'm in an urge.

Comment: For future reference R != R.java-file

Comment: How do you "create fields?"

Comment: (Ctrl + 1 )QuickFix >  **Create field "X" on type "X"** .
Of Course, not everyime Eclipse let you create one of those

Comment: Are you _manually creating new fields_ in the R class? That will not work. The R.java file is automatically generated by Eclipse when you add/modify resources in the `res` directory.

Comment: It seems that i have everything fine.

Comment: It seems i have everything fine.
Don't know what would be

Answer (score -1):

First, why don't u just import

```
com.indestructibles.reproductormp3.R
```

Instead of typing it everytime

Second, post ur XML code, R errors maybe because you wrote something wrong in the XML file, so you've to check your XML files.

Comment: That won't do it. And there's no errors on my res folder nor in tne XML.